# Vectorization of Julia expressions involving both variables and arrays

Tags: julia

I have the following code that I'm using as part of an attempt to implement the [most accurate equation of state](http://iapws.org/relguide/IAPWS95-2016.pdf) for water in Julia 0.6.

```
struct parameterizedeos
  Tc::Float64
  ρc::Float64
  R::Float64

  #parameters for ideal gas portion
  n₀::Vector{Float64}
  γ₀::Vector{Float64}
end

h2o_n₀ = [-8.3204464837497, 6.6832105275932, 3.00632, 0.012436, 0.97315, 1.27950,
          0.96956, 0.24873]
h2o_γ₀ = [1.28728967, 3.53734222, 7.74073708, 9.24437796, 27.5075105]

function Σ(expr)
    return sum(eval(@. expr))
end

function ig(eos, δ, τ)
  end_ = Σ(eos.n₀[4:8]*log(1-exp(-eos.γ₀)*τ))
  return log(δ) + eos.n₀[1] + eos.n₀[2]*τ + eos.n₀[3]*log(τ) + end_
end

Tc = 647.096
ρc = 322
R = 0.46151805

eos = parameterizedeos(Tc,ρc,R,h2o_n₀,h2o_γ₀)
δ₁ = 838.025/ρc
τ₁ = Tc/500
print(ig(eos,δ₁,τ₁))
```

Σ is supposed to be a simple form of the corresponding operator from math, while δ and τ use the nomenclature from the linked reference (dimensionless density and temperature respectively). I get `LoadError: DimensionMismatch("Cannot multiply two vectors")`.

I've played around with all sorts of subexamples in the Julia REPL and they all seem to work just as I'd expect. `Σ(log(1-exp(-h2o_γ₀)*τ))` vectorizes and sums the elements as expected. Heck, `eval(@. h2o_n₀[4:8]*log(1-exp(-h2o_γ₀)*τ)`  happily returns a 5-element vector. But calling `Σ(h2o_n₀[4:8]*log(1-exp(-h2o_γ₀)*τ))` breaks.

I'm a noob at Julia and at arcane things like macros, so anyone could help me figure out what's going on here, that would be great.

Comment: The `Σ(expr)` makes no sense here. The presence of `eval` is a huge red flag. Don't use `eval`. Instead, you can use @stefanbachert's answer, but replace `Σ` with `sum` in the first line. Or you can write: `sum(@. eos.n₀[4:8] * log(1 - exp(-eos.γ₀) * τ₁))`

Comment: `sum(@. eos.n₀[4:8] * log(1 - exp(-eos.γ₀) * τ₁))` also breaks (try it yourself!). As I said in my comment on the accepted answer, only manually adding the `.` to the middle `*` helped, and I think it's a bug in the @. macro, which I thought was supposed to vectorize EVERYTHING. As far as the Σ goes, it was just supposed to make summing a vectorized operation easier, but the bug in the @. macro (or my lack of understanding of it) seems to make that impossible.

Comment: I have tried it, and it works perfectly fine. Regarding the Σ, using `eval` is redundant (and generally advised against.)

Comment: Looking closer, your code is actually failing earlier than you think--the `@.` macro never even comes into play. Your code tries to evaluate `eos.n₀[4:8]*log(1-exp(-eos.γ₀)*τ)`, and fails before it can even pass the result on to the `∑` function. You will have to pass an `Expr` to have any hope of getting it to work.

Comment: Actually, even my last advice (passing an `Expr`) probably won't work. Macros are expanded during parsing, and in your code the parser just sees `@. expr` with no idea what to do with `expr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (using .* and log. and exp. instead)

```
function ig(eos, δ, τ)
  end_ = Σ(eos.n₀[4:8] .* log.(1-exp.(-eos.γ₀)*τ))
  return log(δ) + eos.n₀[1] + eos.n₀[2]*τ + eos.n₀[3]*log(τ) + end_
end
```

Comment: Weird. The `exp.` and `log.` didn't help but using `.*` in the middle did. I actually am thinking this is a bug in the @. macro and may report it, since I thought using that macro was supposed to vectorize EVERYTHING in the expression.

Answer (score 1):

The error you get: `DimensionMismatch("Cannot multiply two vectors")` happens inside the function `ig` when `eos.n₀[4:8]*log(1-exp(-eos.γ₀)*τ)` is evaluated, before the result is supposed to be passed to `Σ`.

Furthermore: `@.` is expanded at parse time in global scope, it adds dots to function calls and operators. `expr` is just a variable, not an operator, not a function call, so therefore `@.` does *nothing*. `eval` also does nothing, so `sum(eval(@. expr))` is identical to just plain `sum(expr)`. But since the program fails *before* that point, this is not your problem.

(**Edit:** Actually `eval` does more than nothing. It does some work; the results are identical, but the extra work is completely wasted.)

Solution: Delete the function `Σ`, you don't need it. Re-write the function `ig` as follows:

```
function ig(eos, δ, τ)
  end_ = sum(@. eos.n₀[4:8] * log(1 - exp(-eos.γ₀) * τ))
  return log(δ) + eos.n₀[1] + eos.n₀[2]*τ + eos.n₀[3]*log(τ) + end_
end
```

**Edit:**

> I've played around with all sorts of subexamples in the Julia REPL and
>   they all seem to work just as I'd expect. `Σ(log(1-exp(-h2o_γ₀)*τ))`
>   vectorizes and sums the elements as expected. Heck, `eval(@. h2o_n₀[4:8]*log(1-exp(-h2o_γ₀)*τ)` happily returns a 5-element vector.
>   But calling `Σ(h2o_n₀[4:8]*log(1-exp(-h2o_γ₀)*τ))` breaks.

Everything here works as expected. `log` and `exp` vectorize automatically, for now, but that behaviour is deprecated. In version 1.0 calling `log` or `exp` (or `sin` or `sqrt`, etc.) on a vector will be an error.

`eval(@. h2o_n₀[4:8]*log(1-exp(-h2o_γ₀)*τ)` vectorizes this expression as expected. (But remove the `eval`, you're just calling it on a value, which it makes no sense to `eval`.)

And `Σ(h2o_n₀[4:8]*log(1-exp(-h2o_γ₀)*τ))` fails because you're trying to multiply two vectors, something that has never worked (you can take the dot-product (using e.g. `'*` or `dot`), or do element-wise multiplication, though.) The fact that you later try to pass the result of this into `Σ`is irrelevant.